# Java Replace multiple substrings(based on indexes)

Tags: java, string, string-parsing

I have a string like

```
'John is a student. He is also a researcher. He is also a human.'
```

I have start and end indexes of `John` and first `He`. Is there a way to replace these substrings simultaneously with `x`. Note that I should not replace second `He` because I have indexes only for the first `He`.

We can obviously iterate over string, copy whenever the pointer is not in the window of substring and putting `x` instead. But, is there a better way than this?

Also, note that indexes are non-overlapping.

Comment: What do you mean "simultaneously"?

Comment: I mean if you replace `John` first. Then the indexes of `He` no longer represent `He`. So, "simultaneously".

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @AndyTurner I got the answer. Please refer to accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing from the end is the best solution.

```
public class NE {
     public Integer startIndex;
     public Integer endIndex;
}

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<NE> {
    public int compare(NE n1, NE n2) {
        return n1.startIndex.compareTo(n2.startIndex);
    }
}

ArrayList<NE> NEList = getIndexes();
Collections.sort(NEList, ner.new CustomComparator());

String finalString = 'John is a student. He is also a researcher. He is also a human.';
for(int i=NEList.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
    NE ne = ner.new NE();
    ne = NEList.get(i);
    finalString = new StringBuilder(finalString).replace(ne.startIndex, ne.endIndex, 'x').toString();
}
System.out.println(finalString);
```

Credits: @AndyTurner

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
String s="John is a student. He is also a researcher.";

        int beginIndex=s.indexOf("He");
        s=s.substring(0, beginIndex)+"x"+s.substring(beginIndex+2,s.length());
```

Output : John is a student. x is also a researcher.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. If indexes I get are of second `He`, then the first `He` should not get replaced.

Comment: it won't be replaced;  the only "he" that we'll be replaced is the one with beginning index is beginIndex , in my case i used beginIndex=s.indexOf(); but you can use the beginIndex you want.

Comment: I suggest you to carefully read the question. I am not searching for `He`. Some black box gives me start and end indexes of `John` and `He`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about a way to change both with the index. But hey, you probably first found the index by searching for the substrings John and He. So you could skip that and use the Strings static method `replaceAll`.

```
String test = "John is a student. He is also a researcher.";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("(John)|(He)", "x"));
```

In fact you are checking if `(John)|(He)` ("John" or "He") are in the string test. If so they are replaced by `"x"`.

`replaceAll` returns a reference to a new String object looking like:

*x is a student. x is also a researcher.*

Comment: I never said I searched and got those indexes. Some API gave me those indexes.

Comment: In that case I am very curious how you got those indexes. You must have given some kind of assignment. So, what did you do to get those indexes?

Comment: Assume I have a function `ArrayList giveIndexes(String s)` which does some black magic and gives me those indexes. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use a placeholder with the same lenght of the word to replace.Then replace the placeholders with x and get the result.

```
 String s = "John is a student. He is also a researcher.";
 int firstStart = 0,firstEnd =4,secondStart=19,secondEnd=21;

 String firstPlaceholder = String.format("%"+(firstEnd - firstStart )+"s", " ").replaceAll(" ", "x");
 String secondPlaceholder = String.format("%"+(secondEnd -secondStart)+"s", " ").replaceAll(" ", "x");

 String result = new StringBuilder(s).replace(firstStart, firstEnd, firstPlaceholder)
                                        .replace(secondStart, secondEnd, secondPlaceholder)
                                        .toString().replaceAll("x[x]+", "x");
 System.out.println( result);
```

output:

```
x is a student. x is also a researcher.
```

hope this can help.

Comment: Great!! This is what I am looking for. Thanks. :D. A small change, though. The first `"xxxx"` should not be hard coded. Can you change the answer such that `"xxxx"` is a string of x's of length of `John`.

Comment: It's not clear from the question that "John" should be replaced with "xxxx" - it looks like it should be replaced with "x".

Comment: @AndyTurner, Yes. I want to replace it with `x`. Please answer if you can achieve that. I will be glad.

Comment: @Achilles-96 no, that's not clear: "I want to replace each character of 'John' with 'x'" describes that. Simply saying "I want to replace "John" with "x"" means replacing the J and deleting the "ohn".

Comment: @AndyTurner, I don't want to replace each character with `x` which is why I asked for editing of the answer. I want entire word to be replaced with `x`. @Mario Cairone, please remove the second part of the answer. As I said, I don't want to replace each character.

Comment: As I said, please don't hard code. Instead of `"x$$$"`, please put something like `"x" + f(4-0)`, where f(n) returns a string of `$`'s of length n-1.

Comment: I made that comment before the latest edit was pushed to me. Accepted. :)

Comment: What if the string is `John is a xxxxxx. He is also a xxxxxxxx.` - the final `replaceAll` would nuke completely unrelated bits of the string.

Comment: Rightly pointed out. `$`'s are a better option. Any random character which is not used generally is a better option. Thanks :D

Comment: Then... what if the string is `John is a x$$$$$. He is also a x$$$$$$$.`?

Comment: That is why I said any character which is not generally used. Uff.

Comment: It's all unnecessary though, if you just the the replaces in reverse: `new StringBuilder(s).replace(secondStart, secondEnd, "x").replace(firstStart, secondStart, "x").toString();`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112428/discussion-between-achilles-96-and-andy-turner).